# How to modify fields in specific sub-documents in an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subdocument

I have a collection where each document has an array of sub-documents, containing several fields. I need to update specific sub-documents based on their fields, but every attempt I've done so far changes the field in all of the arrayed sub-documents

Here is some sample data:

```
{ 
    '_id' : ObjectId('0001'),
    'Region' : 'Northern',
    "Items" : [
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(25), 
            "Name" : "Widget", 
            "ProductType" : "15", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000037"
        }, 
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(30), 
            "Name" : "Gizmo", 
            "ProductType" : "15", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000038"
        },
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(35), 
            "Name" : "Thingy", 
            "ProductType" : "15", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000039"
        }
    ] 
}
```

When I try to use update() with the following query, it updates the ProductType on all array items, not just the one I'm trying to change.

To clarify, I want to change the array item with ItemIdLegacy: "ca-000038" to have ProductType: 20. All other Array items should remain unchanged. Query that I have tried:

```
db.Collection.update({"Items.ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000038"},[{$set: { "Items.ProductType" : "20"} }],{multi: false});
```

This is the **desired** output:

```
{ 
    '_id' : ObjectId('0001'),
    'Region' : 'Northern',
    "Items" : [
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(25), 
            "Name" : "Widget", 
            "ProductType" : "15", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000037"
        }, 
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(30), 
            "Name" : "Gizmo", 
            "ProductType" : "20", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000038"
        },
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(35), 
            "Name" : "Thingy", 
            "ProductType" : "15", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000039"
        }
    ] 
}
```

But this is the actual output of running that query:

```
{ 
    '_id' : ObjectId('0001'),
    'Region' : 'Northern',
    "Items" : [
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(25), 
            "Name" : "Widget", 
            "ProductType" : "20", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000037"
        }, 
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(30), 
            "Name" : "Gizmo", 
            "ProductType" : "20", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000038"
        },
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(35), 
            "Name" : "Thingy", 
            "ProductType" : "20", 
            "ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000039"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple...

EDIT: I have q uery that will allow me to update a single matching element in the array, but I have thousands that would need to be done so one offs don't necessarily work (sure I could parse them all out and spam them to the shell, but I want something more elegant)

Single Element Update:

```
db.Collection.updateOne({"Items.ItemIdLegacy" : "ca-000038"},{ $set: { "Items.$.ProductType" : "20" } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
db.collection.update({
  "Items.ItemIdLegacy": "ca-000038"
},
{
  $set: {
    "Items.$.ProductType": 20
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is [Working Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KjOH8XPtFjS)

Comment: Generated an error when trying to run: `[js] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators`. Also, the sample is small but I have thousands of applicable items spread through arrays on hundreds of documents, need a method that will allow me to edit bulk values

Comment: Which version of mongo you are using?

Comment: v4.0.16 is my version

Comment: Above query uses features from 4.2. I will try to write query for 4.0

Comment: Thanks, it works for updating the single item across multiple documents, but does not allow for multiple updates within the same array (e.g. ItemIdLegacy: { $in: [A, B, C] }). From what I'm gathering on my reading of the problem, this may not be possible with Mongo

Comment: Thats what i understood from your question. So i din not try that.